# Change the color of the navigator

Tags: highcharts

I changed the color over the line of the navigator: color: `'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00)'`
and I changed the color of the line: `lineColor: 'red'`
it is my [chart](http://regexinfo.ru/my_infa/chart/chart_good_scale1.php)

but I can not change the color under the line of the navigator: [ScreenShot](http://regexinfo.ru/my_infa/chart/change_color.JPG)

all code of the navigator:

```
navigator: {
    maskFill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45)',
    series: {
        type: 'areaspline',
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00)',
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        dataGrouping: {
            smoothed: false
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: 'red',
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        shadow: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        reversed: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
navigator: {
    maskFill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45)',
    series: {
        type: 'areaspline',
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00)',
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        dataGrouping: {
            smoothed: false
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: 'red',
        fillColor : {
            linearGradient : {  
                x1 : 0, 
                y1 : 0, 
                x2 : 0, 
                y2 : 1 
            }, 
            stops : [[0, '#FF8000'], [1, '#FFFF00']] 
        },
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        shadow: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        reversed: true
    }
}
```